# chart.js, radar diagram show straight line

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

My require diagram is [spiral diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0pAI.png)  which is slightly same as [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html) radar diagram.
So I tried to change the plugin code to fit into my requirement however I couldn't do that.

So is there any available solution that can match my requirement or approach by which I get the desirable result.

Comment: Is your slightly changed code supposed to be a secret or would you mind sharing it with us so we could actually help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing data points to go from 0 to desired value, I was able to create straight lines.

[image]

```
data: [8,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0],

data: [0,0,6,0,0,0,0],

data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6],
```

Example: https://codepen.io/Nurech/pen/xxpgwxv

Comment: Yes the Idea is good but all node may not be have value 0. suppose every node is not 0 then it again will create same layout

Comment: Okay, but then again - you provided no further details nor a single line of code of what you expect this to do. Please reproduce the problem online (e.g StackBlitz), explain the problem in detail and what should be the end result.

Comment: I can have data to these sections https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0pAI.png, which can be any number between 0 to 100 and need only this type of graph.

however I tried to take multiple data rows with different different  value like you did above 3 arrays that way I can achieve this